# ICECAST - When does the listeners_peak stat is updated

Tags: icecast

I'm using IceCast 2.4.2 for my online radio server.
I've noticed that the stats have a listeners' peak stat that represents the number of maximum concurrent connections to my mount.

My question is when does this stat update? is this the peak for the day? the week? the hour?

official docs say

```
Peak concurrent number of listener connections for this mount point.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is for the life-cycle of the source client connection.
Any mountpoint specific values are limited to its life-cycle and will be reset upon disconnection of the source client. As at that point the mountpoint ceases to exist.

The global values are for the life-cycle of the Icecast server process (since it was started).

Comment: Yes, I thought that too. but at some point, the values started bouncing up and down while the server was never restarted.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I thought of global values, those are since server start. For moun points those are scoped by the source client connection. If the source client disconnect and reconnects, they will be reset to zero.